# The following packages have unmet dependencies. (Zorin OS 16)

Tags: linux, zorin

I am relatively new to Linux and I just fell in love with Zorin OS 16. However, there are still some windows programs that I want to use from time to time which is why I would like to install wine. 
Following multiple instructions on the Internet, I always get the following error when running `sudo apt-get install winehq-stable`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 7.0.0.0~impish-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this forum post that may help you.
https://forum.zorin.com/t/problems-installing-wine/14753

It appears I had installed the incorrect repositories and had to remove them.